# Inheritance in Object Oriented JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototypal-inheritance

I have 3 objects, **Science**, **Physics** and **Mathematics**.

I want the last two object *(**Physics** and **Mathematics**)*
to inherit the protoype properties of ***Science***.

Yet I want both *Mathematics* & *Physics* to update the inherited properties and define theirs. This is done, but I keep getting **undefined** when I try to access the Science properties and method via an instance of *Physics*. What could be wrong with my code.

```js
function log(elem) {
  return console.log(elem);
}
//create supertype => Science
function Science() {}

//define Science prototype props
Science.prototype = {
  constructor: Science,
  dificulty: "Variable",
  universal: true,
  type: "science",
  name: "science",
  hasSubFields() {
    return true;
  },
};

//create 2 sub fields : Mathematics and Physics to inherit props from Science
function Mathematics(subField) {
  this.subField = subField;
}
function Physics() {}

//let mathematics & Physics inherit science props
Mathematics.prototype = 
Object.create(Science.prototype);
Physics.prototype = 
Object.create(Science.prototype);
Physics.prototype.constructor = Physics;

//over write Mathematics inherited props and physics
Mathematics.prototype = {
  constructor: Mathematics,
  name: "Mathematics",
  type: "Pure and applied Science",
};

Physics.prototype = {
  name: "Physics",
  dificulty: "80%",
  type: "Physical Science",
  subFields: ["Electricity", "Mechanics", "Sound", "Optics", "Waves"],
};

//make instance of Physics
let mechanics = new Physics();
mechanics.name = "mechanics";
mechanics.subFields = ["linear", "force", "force fileds"];

log(mechanics.universal);
```

Comment: Instantiating the parent class to serve as the prototype of a child class is odd and may bite you in some circumstances! I recommend you replace `Mathematics.prototype = new Science()` with `Mathematics.prototype = Object.create(Science.prototype)`

Comment: ````Mathematics.prototype 
    =Object.create(Science.prototype);
    Physics.prototype = 
    Object.create(Science.prototype);
     Physics.prototype.constructor  = Physics;````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Physics.prototype = new Science();

//...

Physics.prototype = {
  name: "Physics",
  dificulty: "80%",
  type: "Physical Science",
  subFields: ["Electricity", "Mechanics", "Sound", "Optics", "Waves"],
};
```

This second line is overwriting the first one. Once the code is done, the prototype is just the new object. There is no longer any relationship to `Science`, and thus no `universal` property to inherit.

Instead of replacing `prototype`, you need to add to it:

```
Physics.prototype = new Science();

//...

Physics.prototype.name = "Physics";
Physics.prototype.dificulty = "80%";
Physics.prototype.subFields = "Physical Science";
Physics.prototype.name = ["Electricity", "Mechanics", "Sound", "Optics", "Waves"];
```

Or:

```
Physics.prototype = new Science();

//...

Object.assign(Physics.prototype, {
  name: "Physics",
  dificulty: "80%",
  type: "Physical Science",
  subFields: ["Electricity", "Mechanics", "Sound", "Optics", "Waves"],
});
```

`Mathematics` will need similar changes.

```js
function log(elem) {
  return console.log(elem);
}
//create supertype => Science
function Science() {}

//define Science prototype props
Science.prototype = {
  constructor: Science,
  dificulty: "Variable",
  universal: true,
  type: "science",
  name: "science",
  hasSubFields() {
    return true;
  },
};

//create 2 sub fields : Mathematics and Physics to inherit props from Science
function Mathematics(subField) {
  this.subField = subField;
}
function Physics() {}

//let mathematics & Physics inherit science props
Mathematics.prototype = Object.create(Science.prototype);
Physics.prototype = Object.create(Science.prototype);
Physics.prototype.constructor = Physics;

//over write Mathematics inherited props and physics
Object.assign(Mathematics.prototype, {
  constructor: Mathematics,
  name: "Mathematics",
  type: "Pure and applied Science",
});

Object.assign(Physics.prototype, {
  name: "Physics",
  dificulty: "80%",
  type: "Physical Science",
  subFields: ["Electricity", "Mechanics", "Sound", "Optics", "Waves"],
})

//make instance of Physics
let mechanics = new Physics();
mechanics.name = "mechanics";
mechanics.subFields = ["linear", "force", "force fileds"];

log(mechanics.universal);
```

Comment: ````Object.assign(Physics.prototype, {
  name: "Physics",
  dificulty: "80%",
  type: "Physical Science",
  subFields: ["Electricity", "Mechanics", "Sound", "Optics", "Waves"],
});```` returns undefined

Comment: I've added a snippet to my answer which successfully uses Object.assign.